# Convergent sequence and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

It's trivial that any sequence in a Hausdorff space converges to at most one point. What about its inverse?
E.g. If a topological space have the property that any sequence in it converges to at most one point, is it a Hausdorff space?

If this is not true, a counterexample will be appreciated.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2943399/a-separation-axiom-equivalent-to-uniqueness-of-limits-of-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be an uncountable set and consider topological space $(X,  \tau_{co-countable})$. Then every sequence
converges to at most one point, but the space is not Hausdorff.in the cocountable topologyall convergent sequences are eventually constant, so they converge to at most one point.

Comment: Being eventually constant does not imply (in general ) that the limit is unique (e.g. the indiscrete topology), but it *is* enough here because $X$ is $T_1$.

Comment: BTW, there is a (complicated) example of a *sequential* space that is not Hausdorff, but in which limits of convergent sequences are unique (a US space, as it's also called).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes! exactly.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What does US mean?

Comment: *U*nique *S*equential limits.